# Opensource TCAP/MAP C/C++ implementation

Tags: c, encoding, gsm, decoding, asn.1

I am looking for C/C++ implementation for encoding and decoding of TCAP/MAP layers. I am already aware of [osmocom](https://github.com/osmocom/libasn1c). I would like to know whether there exists any other reliable opensource tool for this goal?

Comment: Hello Abolfazl, did you find any other implementations?